# Can we find the RMS of a signal from its envelope?

Tags: discrete-signals, hilbert-transform

I’d like to know if it’s possible to calculate the RMS of a signal from its envelope which we can find from Hilbert transform?

Comment: Yes, that's possible.

Comment: @Reza Was the answer below what you were looking for, or something else?

Comment: Yes. I accepted that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a real signal $x(t)$, its complex analytic signal $x_a(t)$, and the envelope as the absolute magnitude of the analytic signal: $|x_a(t)|$, we can relate the RMS of the envelope to the RMS of the signal as follows:

For the simpler case of a real signal with no DC component, the RMS of the envelope will simply be $\sqrt{2}$ larger than the RMS of the signal.

When a DC component exists, the relationship is as follows:

$$(\textit{RMS}\{x(t) \})^2  = \frac{(\textit{RMS}\{x_a(t) \})^2+|\overline{x_a(t)|}^2}{2}$$

Where:

$\textit{RMS}\{x(t) \}$ : The RMS of the real waveform $x(t)$

$\textit{RMS}\{x_a(t) \}$ : The RMS of the analytic waveform $x_a(t)= x(t) + j\hat{x}(t)$

$\hat{x}(t)$: Hilbert Transform of $x(t)$

$\overline{|x_a(t)|}$: mean of the envelope which is the DC component of $x(t)$ and $x_a(t)$.

And the root-mean-square (RMS) of $x_a(t)$ as:

$\textit{RMS}\{x_a(t) \} =  \sqrt{\frac{1}{N}\sum_N (x_a(t)x_a^*(t))}$

And similarly the root-mean-square (RMS) of $x(t)$ is:

$\textit{RMS}\{x(t) \} =  \sqrt{\frac{1}{N}\sum_N (x(t)^2)}$

**DETAILS AND DERIVATION:**

The relationships used are easy to visualize in the frequency domain starting from the transfer function for the analytic signal, given below:

[image: Transfer function]

As given by this transfer function, the analytic signal has no negative frequency ($\omega<0$) components, passes DC ($\omega=0$) without modification, and doubles the magnitude of the positive frequency ($\omega>0$) components.

A real signal is Hermitian symmetric, so excluding DC, would have half of its power in the negative frequency domain ($\omega<0$), and the other half in the positive frequency domain ($\omega>0$).  The doubling of the positive frequency component is a doubling in magnitude, or four times in power, from the half of the total power of the original signal that occupies the positive frequencies. From that we see how the Analytic Signal will have an RMS quantity that is $\sqrt{2}$ larger when there is no DC component. The DC component contributes directly to the power leading to a relationship for RMS quantity in the analytic signal and the original real waveform as developed below.

Total power in the spectrum for real waveform $x(t)$ is comprised of power in the negative frequency domain, power at DC, and power in the positive frequency domain. Since the power in the positive and negative frequency domains are equal, this can be expressed as:

$$P_x = P_{-\omega} + P_{dc} + P_{+\omega} = P_{dc} + 2P_{+\omega}  \tag{1}\label{1}$$

Where:

$P_x$ total power

$P_{-\omega}$ component of total power in negative frequency domain

$P_{dc}$ component of total power at DC

$P_{-\omega}$ component of total power in positive frequency domain

Given Parseval's Theorem, the total power in the spectrum is equal to the total power in real waveform $x(t)$, and the RMS is the square root of the total power, thus:

$$\textit{RMS}_x = \sqrt{P_x}$$

Similarly the total power in the spectrum for the analytic waveform $x_a(t)$, following the transfer function provided, and its RMS quantity is given as:

$$P_{xa} = P_{dc} + 4P_{+\omega} \tag{2}\label{2}$$
$$\textit{RMS}_{xa} = \sqrt{P_{xa}}$$

Where

$P_{xa}$ : total power in the spectrum for analytic signal $x_a(t)$

Thus, for the simpler case of no DC component, we have the relationship that the RMS of the analytic signal is $\sqrt{2}$ larger than the RMS of the real waveform:

$$\textit{RMS}_{xa} = \sqrt{4P_{+\omega}} = \sqrt{2}\textit{RMS}_{x}=  \sqrt{2}\sqrt{2P_{+\omega}} \text{   (no DC case)}$$

When a DC component exists, we have the following relationship between the RMS of the analytic signal and the RMS of the real waveform:

$$\textit{RMS}_{xa} = \sqrt{P_{dc}+4P_{+\omega}} $$
$$\textit{RMS}_{x} = \sqrt{P_{dc}+2P_{+\omega}}$$

The mean of the envelope is the DC component of the signal:

$$P_{dc} = \overline{|x_a(t)|}$$

With that we can determine the RMS of the waveform from the mean and RMS of the envelope summarized as follows:

From \ref{2}:

$$P_{+\omega} = \frac{(\textit{RMS}_{xa})^2-P_{dc}}{4} = \frac{(\textit{RMS}_{xa})^2-\overline{|x_a(t)|}^2}{4}$$

Substituting the above result into \ref{1}:

$$P_x = (\textit{RMS}_x)^2 = P_{dc}+2_{+\omega} = \overline{|x_a(t)|^2} + \frac{(\textit{RMS}_{xa})^2-\overline{|x_a(t)|}^2}{2}$$

Resulting in:

$$(\textit{RMS}_x)^2 =\frac{(\textit{RMS}_{xa})^2+\overline{|x_a(t)|}^2}{2}$$